# How can I disable whole beamer animations on a slide?

Tags: beamer

I generally insert overlays after I finish inserting presentation content. Currently I am updating a long presentation with full of overlays. I would like to disable them altogether after I complete the update. Is there an option that I can pass to beamer so that it stops generating zillions of additional overlay slides on every build?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- to disable overlays globally, you could use the `handout` option
- if you only want to disable them for a specific slide you can pick whatever overlay number you would like to see and use `\begin{frame}<your number>` to show only one of the overlays

---

```
\documentclass[
  handout
]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc\pause def
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<2>
abc\pause def
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```